# Total differentiation, is this true: $D(Df(a))(a) = f$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ be linear.

We have proven that for $T$ linear it is:
$$
D T(a) = T.
$$

---

So it should imply that:
$$
D(Df(a))(a) = f.
$$
Right? This seems to be trivial, but I had a long discussion with a fellow student who keeps saying that it is $0$ and also, that considering such examples is absolutely irrelevant in mathematical praxis.

So who is wrong...?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think the OP's notation is OK. In this usage $Df(a)$ is not a vector in $\mathbb R^q,$ it's the linear map that approximates the map $f-f(a)$ near $a.$

Comment: You are right, it is trivial. Your fellow student would do well to understand why.

Comment: I dont know the notation $DT$, we only (yet) defined the total derivative of a function **in a point**. So I only know $DT(a)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful what you're taking the derivative of. $\mathrm Df(a):x\mapsto \mathrm Df(a)(x)$ is a linear map for fixed $a$. However, the map $\mathrm Df:a\mapsto\mathrm Df(a)$ is a (usually) nonlinear map assigning to each $a$ a linear map.

Differentiating the first one will return the same map, since it's linear, and the derivative of a linear map is exactly that linear map. However, differentiating the second one will give you something different, and it's what we usually care about.

In the first case, if $f$ is linear, then you will indeed get $\mathrm D(\mathrm Df(a))(b)=f$ for all $a$ and $b$. In the second case, since $\mathrm Df(a)$ is a constant, you will get $\mathrm D(\mathrm Df)(a)=0$. Notice the meaningful difference in notation. The way you wrote it, we should actually mean the first case  Your friend is right in that this is not a case you'll often see discussed, though.

Comment: Note the hypothesis that $f:\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R^q$ is linear, so $Df:\mathbb R^p\times\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R^q$ maps $Df(a)(b)=f(b)$.

Thus, for each $a\in\mathbb R^p$, $Df(a)=f$.

(unless you want to make a distinction between the space and its tangent space, which is not usually done at this stage).

Comment: And thus $D^2f=0$; indeed, $f(a+h)=f(a)+f(h)+0$ by linearity, therefore $Df(a)=f$ for all $a$ i.e. $Df(a)[h]=f(h)$. But then, $Df(a+k)[h]-Df(a)[h]=f(h)-f(h)=0$ for all $h,k$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Maybe you could mention that in the second case the second derivative is indeed the zero function? So in a sense both of the people mentioned in the post are right :)

Comment: I don't understand the second case. You say $Df(a)$ is a constant but isn't it a linear function? Because you defined it this way: $Df:a↦Df(a)$; so $Df(a)$ is a linear function, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's a linear function. But it's always the same linear function, independent of $a$, assuming that $f$ itself is linear. We have a function which maps vectors to functions (which are also vectors in an appropriate vector space!), and as such it is a constant function, because it always maps to the same function.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense now! This is also why when using the **usual** one-dimensional differentiation, we get $0$, since the second case is applied right? Because when we have $f(x)=2x$, then $f'(x)=2$, as a linear mapping it is again $x \mapsto 2x$. But here we (usually) don't look at it as a linear mapping but as what you said: $Df:a \mapsto 2$. And then the differentiation of that is indeed $0$, as we would have calculated it in 1-dimensional analysis. Do I understand this correctly now?

Comment: @LukasNiessen Yes, exactly.

Comment: I have the following question that is not directly connected to the question. When we say $f$ is twice differentiable; we mean that $Df(a):x↦Df(a)(x)$ is differentiable also, right? And not that $Df(a)$ is differentiable for all $a$, right? Because that would be always true as we've seen here.

Comment: @LukasNiessen Yes, exactly.